# existence of an "inverse" adjoint in Banach Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let X,Y be Banach spaces and S a bounded operator $S: Y' \rightarrow X'$ where $'$ denotes the dual space or the adjoint operator depending on what it is on.

Then

$$ \exists \ \ T \in B(X,Y) : T'=S \iff  S'(\hat{X}) \subset \hat{Y} $$

where $\hat{X}$ is the image of $X$ under the canonical isometry $\phi:X \rightarrow X''$

$$\phi(x)x'= x'(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \forall x\in X, x'\in X'$$

I fail to see how the completeness assumption is used. I imagine it will be useful since it gives us that both $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$ are closed.

This is what I thought:

Assume $ S'(\hat{X}) \subset \hat{Y}$ then for each $x$ there is an element of $Y$ (call it $Tx$) such that $S'(\hat{x})= \widehat{Tx}$

then let $y'\in Y'$,
$S( y'(x))= \hat{x}(S(y'))=S'(\hat{x})(y')= (\widehat{Tx})y'=y'(T(x))=(T'y')x$

therefore $S=T'$ (assuming such $T'$ exists, but it is not too hard to show that T is a bounded linear operator)

I think that for the converse the argument is essentially the same... what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completeness is not needed. People often state results for Banach spaces because this is the context they are working in; even though the result may be true for general normed linear spaces. Besides, "Banach" is shorter than "normed linear".

For any $S :Y'\to X'$ there is one, and only one, candidate for the *pre-adjoint* of $S$: namely, the restriction of $S'$ to the image of $X$ in $X''$. The only issue is whether this candidate takes values in $Y$. The diagram-chasing part of solution does not involve any topology, in particular does not rely on completeness.

(Tangential: here is a [nice example](https://mathoverflow.net/q/57277) of a surjective isometry without a pre-adjoint.)

Comment: thanks, so is my proof correct (at least for one direction?)

Comment: @Moritzplatz Yes, it is correct. The other direction is trivial: if $S$ has a pre-adjoint $T$, then $S'=T''$, and $T''$ clearly maps $\hat X$ into $\hat Y$.